# GitHub に ssh で接続できない

Tags: github, ssh

GitHub に ssh で接続できなくなりました。

**~/.ssh/config**

```
Host github.com
  User git
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/鍵名
  Port 443
```

**実行ログ**

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
XXX@YYY .ssh %  ssh -vT  git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/XXX/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/XXX/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/XXX/.ssh/鍵名 type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/XXX/.ssh/鍵名-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Server: openresty/1.11.2.1
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 06:07:13 GMT
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: Content-Type: text/html
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: Content-Length: 179
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5: Connection: close
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 6: 
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 7: <html>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 8: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 9: <body bgcolor="white">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 10: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 11: <hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.1</center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 12: </body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 13: </html>
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

22ポートだと下記が表示され、タイムアウトになってしまいます。

```
XXX@YYY .ssh %  ssh -vT  git@github.com       
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/XXX/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github port 22.
```

色々調べたのですが、わからず、どなたかに解決策をご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: 「できなくなった」ということは以前はできていた、という事でしょうか？

Comment: そうです。。。以前はできてました。。。